# mensaje javascript al destiquear un checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

buenas, estoy comenzando a utilizar jquery así que aun no se mucho, quisiera hacer lo siguiente. tengo un checkbox. simple. pero que estoy cargando por defecto 'checked' y quiero que al tratar de destiquiarlo me salga un mensaje de confirmación en javascript. como podría resolver esto?

```html
<div class="switch">
  <label>Guardar<input type="checkbox" value="1" class="check" checked><span class="lever"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Te recomendaria que agregaras tu codigo, para que sea mas facil apoyarte

Comment: buenas, en realidad solo tendria el codigo del checkbox normal.. con la diferencia que este lo tengo tiqueado, es por eso mi pregunta.. pero voi agregar el codigo de todas formas.

Comment: Si agrega tu codigo para poder revisarlo y asi buscar entre todos una solucion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías resolverlo así:

- Suscribirte al evento `change` del `checkbox`.
- Si no esta `checked`, entonces pedir confirmación.
- Dependiendo de la respuesta obtenida, dejar `checked` o no, el `checkbox`.

```js
document.getElementById('checkbox').addEventListener('change', function() {
  // Si no esta checked
  if (!this.checked) {
    this.checked = !confirm('¿Esta seguro que no quiere guardar?');
  }
});
```

```html
<label><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" checked />Guardar!</label>
```

Comment: gracias era lo que necesitaba, solo una consulta mas.. es posible lanzar una petición ajax, al aceptar el confirm?

Comment: @max, si, claro. Puede hacerlo justo debajo de la linea del `confirm`. agregan, por ejemplo, `/* si acepto no guardar */ if(!this.checked) { /* aqui codigo ajax */ }`.